# Arduino + Industrial Interface

Tags: arduino, ethernet, industrial

In a project, we need to drive a linear motor module (some high tech fancy industry thing) with something as simple as an Arduino. Basically we need to get the speed of the Motor and send its new commands back. In between I'll implement a controller and logic.

To be honest, I only got a rough idea, how industry (ethernet or other) standard/interfaces work, and I got absolutely no idea, if it is even possible to interface such a fancy thing with an Arduino.

I've got the options for the following things:

Sercos III, Profinet IO, EtherNet/IP, EtherCat
possibly also: CANopen, Profibus

Are there any libraries/known projects in this direction? Or is it strictly impossible? I found 2 projects about profibus, but they didn't really seem to be reproducable in the near feature, without significant efforts.
Thanks for any hints, advices etc.!

Comment: I guess the most common used industrial protocolls would be CAN and Profibus (which is based on a RS485 interface). Especially for CAN there should be some Arduino libs as at least the Arduino DUE (and the DigiX which I like more because of the better interfaces) provide a built-in CAN interface. For others are CAN shields available if I remember right.

Answer (score 0):

Very interessting discussion about CAN on Arduino DUE: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131096.0 Same should work for the DigiX as it is 100% pin- and code compatible (and still available ;-) )